# Can someone explain the difference please (je devais/j'avais dû)

Tags: grammaire

what is the meaning difference between this two sentence?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to FL. Have you read the [help section?](https://french.stackexchange.com/help) [Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: For a start you have to notice that the tenses are different. This can be found with the help of a [conjugation table](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/verb-conjugations/devoir/). Then when to use the [imparfait](https://laits.utexas.edu/tex/gr/tap7.html) and when to use the [plus-que-parfait](https://laits.utexas.edu/tex/gr/tap9.html). Each sentence will be used in a different context, the reason you see a similar translation in English is that English doesn't express the difference in aspect between the two.

Comment: Please include the text of the image for accessibility in addition to heeding the comments above on research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"J'avais dû finir" (plus-que-parfait de l'indicatif): this expression is used to indicate an action that had to be completed before a specific moment in the past. For example,

> 'J'avais dû finir mes devoirs avant de sortir.' = "I had to finish my homework before going out."

"Je devais finir" (imparfait de l'indicatif): this expression is used to indicate an action that had to be completed regularly or continuously in the past. For example,

> 'Je devais finir mes devoirs avant de sortir tous les soirs.' = "I had to finish my homework before going out every night."

NB

J'avais dû finir peut signifier j'avais été forcé, ou bien encore, il est vraisemblable que j'avais fini. (merci @Frank).

Comment: _J'avais dû finir_ peut signifier j'avais été _forcé_, ou bien encore, il est _vraisemblable_ que j'avais fini.

Comment: @Frank Merci. A reference for this statement?

Comment: @Frank I am not a native speaker but If you want to express that you were forced to finish something in the past, I would rather use the phrase "J'avais été forcé(e) de finir" or "On m'avait forcé(e) à finir".

Comment: You can, but _dû_ is from _devoir_, and _devoir faire quelque chose_ is close to _être forcé de faire quelque chose_. I don't have a reference handy, but I'm a native speaker.

Comment: @Frank D'accord. Je te fais confiance:-)!

Comment: @Dimitris Il ne faut pas oublier non plus que dans la plupart des cas, on traduirait *being forced to* par *être* ***obligé·e*** *de*.

Comment: Note that *Je devais finir mes devoirs avant de sortir* doesn't imply it is a repetitive action nor that the homework were actually completed.

Comment: Il y avoir encore d'autres sens dans un récit : "j'avais dû finir mes devoirs ..."  On se place au moment du récit on l'on a déjà fini les devoir et on est sorti. Pour "je devais finir mes devoirs ...", on se place au moment du récit où l'on est encore à la maison qu'on n'a pas encore fait/terminé/commencé ses devoirs. L'imparfait n'est pas que le temps des habitude/répétitions.